# How to split off a part of a string in c++?

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ at the moment and I want to make a code where the user gives in a combination of two words to process. For example the user put in "*echo something*" and the code see that threre is an "*echo*" in there then this echo will be splitten off and the rest is gona be printed out on the screen. At the moment here I am:

```
if (income.find("read ") != string::npos){
...
//here I need some help!
...
}
```

Could someone help me please. Thanks!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the [substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) member function of `std::string`.

In your case,

```
auto pos = income.find("read ");
if (pos!= string::npos){
std::cout<<income.substr(pos+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two words you can try storing them both separately and if any of them is equal to "echo" skip it and print the other word.

```
std::string p, q ;
std::cin >> p >> q ;

if (p == "echo"){
    std::cout << q ;
}
else if(q == "echo"){
    std::cout << p ;
}
else std::cout << p << " " << q << "\n" ; // if neither of them are equal to "echo" simply print the original sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find target word and what comes after it

```
std::string target = "read ";
std::string after_target;

auto target_pos = income.find (target);

if (target_pos != std::string::npos)
    after_target = str.substr (target_pos + target.size ());
```